# how to use application library for Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am new in backbone.js. And i have to use application library for Backbone.js .

But I am not understand how to use or implement can you pls help me to use application library for Backbone.js .

Application library is:
[Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/)

Comment: Never used Marionette before. But I'd suggest looking the screencasts in the Marionette website. Additionally see if the download includes sample code.

Comment: No there is no sample code in download..In download all are js files..

Comment: Yeah the Marionette site seems very sparse on actual documentation.

Comment: Maybe try these page: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki

Comment: I found [this](https://netguru.co/blog/posts/marionette-js-and-backbone-a-perfect-match#) blog post to be very helpful when trying to come up to speed with Marionette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be honest, your question has less details than it should to provide you short answer, so the answer will be long) . So a few words about Marionette - its main task to structure your BB application, provide you some additional structure abstraction and save you from boilerplate code.

So lets start implementation.

1) [Application](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md) -   Its the point your application starts. You application contains from [Modules](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md), if roughly, application task is to start necessary modules, manage communication between them and render initial views.

for e.g

```
// instance your app
var App = new Marionette.Application;

//define regions
App.addRegions({
    'main' : '#main',
    'foot' : '#foot'
});

//add init function
App.addInitializer(function(){
    App.main.show(new MainView);
})
```

2) [Modules](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md) - the key part of your app. Its part of you application like some simple widget(feedback form, link list or etc.) or something more complicated, like single page app with routes, models and so on. It also coud be some services, like social networks auth, so the independent logic part of you application is module. So try to decompose your BB app on such blocks. On my practice, i used to decompose application by 2 steps - 1) get widget-based elements 2) get services.

for e.g lets define some simple mod. Let it be simple widget

```
App.module('starsrating', function(starsRating){
    $(function(){
        $('.rating').ratePlugin({
           stars: 10,
           onRate: function(){
               ///
           }
        })
    })
});
```

3) Views - [ItemView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md), [CollectionView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md), [CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md), [Layout](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md)

Its magic wands helps you to avoid boilerplate code in your app. I strongly recommend you to read doc about it closely and begin implementation exacttly with views, usually its the weakest part in BB app.

Hope it will help to start implementation. If you need some more info, code examples, ping me.

Comment: hello Evgeniy. I am very much new in backbone max one week and now i have to use Marionette plugin.  I am totally confused with plugin because not perfect in backbone.

Comment: to start with Marionette its mostly enough to clarify with Models and Collections. When i began develop with BB this link (https://github.com/jcreamer898/RequireJS-Backbone-Starter) helped me a lot. Check it out and raise questions.

Comment: I want to add 2 template main.html and main2.html and for this i create two view view.js and view2.js. but not able to add two template.  Approch: add main2.html in template and view2.js in view. and edit id of view2 . but showing only one template

Comment: the logic is - Application render views in regions -> views includes templates. It would be great if you could create jsfiddle for tests

Comment: please attach all external resourses to js fiddle (require, underscore, backbone, templates and so on) to make it work

Comment: @sonalgoyal, you can [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eGbbQ/2/) fiddle as a Marionette template.